# Dollar sign appears as end of line characters in Vim and it's impossible to remove

Tags: vim

When I try to execute my script I got `^M` is an invalid character but in Vim, I see `$` upon entering `:set list`

I tried `:%s/^V^M//g` but it says `^M` pattern is not found

I guessed this occurred because I used some `.vimrc` I found [here](http://amix.dk/vim/vimrc.html) which converts the end of line characters to `$`

Without figuring this out, my only option would be retyping my script.

Comment: Your file doesn't contain dollar signs; that's simply the character used by `vim` with `set list` to display whatever is interpreted as an end-of-line.

Comment: Your question title is misleading.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your script consistently has `^M` line endings, and therefore got detected as `fileformat=dos`. `:setlocal fileformat?` will tell you.

To convert this file to Unix (LF) line endings, just `:setlocal fileformat=unix` and `:write`, or combine this in `:w ++ff=unix`.

If you never want Vim to detect such files (and show the `^M` instead), put `:set fileformats-=dos` into your `~/.vimrc` (or edit an existing config).

Answer (score 2):

`se nolist` and the dollar signs will disappear.

No matter the OS, you always have line endings in your text.

Line endings are whitespace and always present, but usually just not shown.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows or *nix?

in windows, you can replace ^M as `ctlr-q ctrl-m` to input the ^M.  In *nix, you can just use dos2unix to translate your script file to unix format.

Answer (score 0):

If after opening your file you don’t see `^M` at the end of line, but when you try sourcing it vim does show complains about `^M` in various places the only thing you need to do is `w ++ff=unix` and reopen this file.

When you open a file vim detects line ending format. Thus trying to substitute `^M` will not work: all detected line endings are converted into internal string end. E.g. when file format is dos like in your case it looks like

```
set nocompatible\r\nset ignorecase\r\n...
```

(where `\r` is carriage return, sometimes represented as `^M`, and `\n` is line feed character, and `\r\n` sequence is dos line ending). When file format is unix it looks like

```
set nocompatible\nset ignorecase\n...
```

. For mac it looks like

```
set nocompatible\rset ignorecase\r...
```

. But if vim correctly detected line ending *all* these files transform into

```
"set nocompatible"
"set ignorecase"
"..."
```

C strings in internal structure representing buffer, each string represents one line. No `\r` and no `\n` are there.

When you do `:w` files are converted back into a sequence of bytes. `:w ++ff=unix` forces line endings. Reopening is needed because `fileformat` setting is not changed in this case thus next `w` without `++ff` will save with dos line endings again. When you reopen line endings are redetected and `fileformat` setting is reassigned. You can do `:set fileformat=unix` manually after `:w ++ff=unix`, but `:e` is much faster to type.